# Vision Text Recogniser giving nil result

Tags: ios, swift, google-contacts-api, vision-api, image-text

I hope you are doing well, I am stuck with an strange problem. I have implemented Vision Text Recogniser and after successfully extract the image and assign that image to visionImage but I am getting error = nil and also the result = nil. There is nil coming in result block i have followed the google documentation link https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/ios/recognize-text . but the result is nil.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {


            imgView.image = pickedImage

            // -----
            let visionImage = VisionImage(image: pickedImage)

            textRecognizer.process(visionImage) { (result, error) in

                guard error == nil, let result = result else {
                    // ...

                    return
                }

                print("THE RESULT", result?.text)

            // -----
        }
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Please help me with that or specify why reason of that nil coming in result block. so that I can fix it.

A big Thank you in advance, waiting for your response.

Regards,
Azeem Usmani

Comment: What image are you using? Also, is the pickedImage there? Do you enter into the if let block?

Comment: the image is picked from mobile gallery through imagePicker delegate. the pickedImage is the image i have picked from gallery. the type if UIImage.

Comment: no, I mean, literally... what is the image? Does it actually contain text? Also, does the if let block actually run?

Comment: You say your result isn’t printed. Does it actually print “THE RESULT nill” or something else?

Comment: @Fogmeister yes it is  printing "“THE RESULT nill”".  And i am uploading a visiting card image.

Comment: What is the output for `print(result)`?

Comment: @Fogmeister it literally shows nil as output.

Comment: If `result` was nil then your code wouldn't print "THE RESULT nil" (which you said it is printing). Your `guard let result = result else { return }` would stop that. So... `result.text` is `nil`. But what is the value of `result`? Put `print(result)` in your code and show the output. NOTE: NOT `print(result.text)`.

Comment: I have printed  result not result.text but it still showing same output nil.

Comment: Can you put your updated code into the question. If result was nil then currently it shouldn’t print anything. Thanks